# Video sequence in Sprite Kit leads to messy interruptions

Tags: objective-c, video, sprite-kit, sequence, avqueueplayer

I want to create a video sequence in Sprite Kit and use the following code:

```
@interface VideScreenNode()
@end

@implementation VideScreenNode

- (void)setupVideoSequence
{
    AVPlayerItem * intro  = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[self geturlFromFileName:@"Video1" andType:@"mp4"]];
    AVPlayerItem * video1 = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[self geturlFromFileName:@"Video2" andType:@"mp4"]];
    AVPlayerItem * video2 = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[self geturlFromFileName:@"Video3" andType:@"mp4"]];
    AVPlayerItem * video3 = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[self geturlFromFileName:@"Video4" andType:@"mp4"]];
    AVPlayerItem * video4 = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[self geturlFromFileName:@"Video5" andType:@"mp4"]];
    AVPlayerItem * outro  = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[self geturlFromFileName:@"Video6" andType:@"mp4"]];

    AVQueuePlayer * queuePlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:@[intro, video1, video2, video3, video4, outro]];
    SKVideoNode * sequenceNode = [[SKVideoNode alloc] initWithAVPlayer: queuePlayer];

    sequenceNode.position = CGPointMake(512, 384);
    [sequenceNode play];
    [self addChild:sequenceNode];
}

#pragma mark - helper

- (NSURL *)geturlFromFileName:(NSString *)name
                      andType:(NSString *)type
{
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: name ofType:type]];
}
```

The video sequence works just fine, but there is a small interruption between each clip. How do I achieve a seamless transition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever heard of a thing called singleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add in a call on the `AVQueuePlayer` that you have.  Such as:

```
[queuePlayer prerollAtRate:float completionHandler:^(BOOL finished)completionHandler];
```

This will load the files into memory and prepare them to play.  This will have an impact on performance, depending on the size of the clips.  It should smooth out the transitions that you have.  However, you will need to watch out, as if the `status` property is not `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay`, this will fail.

Comment: Thanks! I also managed to eliminate the gaps by using AVMutableComposition